# Future predictions with LSTM

Tags: python, lstm

I want to ask how to predict future for some time-frame with the LSTM model below. Thanks
https://github.com/jaungiers/LSTM-Neural-Network-for-Time-Series-Prediction

I tried `model.predict(x_test)` but the predict command is not recognized.

```
def main():
    configs = json.load(open('config_MS.json', 'r'))
    if not os.path.exists(configs['model']['save_dir']): os.makedirs(configs['model']['save_dir'])

data = DataLoader(
    os.path.join('data', configs['data']['filename']),
    configs['data']['train_test_split'],
    configs['data']['columns']
)

model = Model()
model.build_model(configs)
x, y = data.get_train_data(
    seq_len=configs['data']['sequence_length'],
    normalise=configs['data']['normalise']
)


steps_per_epoch = math.ceil((data.len_train - configs['data']['sequence_length']) / configs['training']['batch_size'])
model.train_generator(
    data_gen=data.generate_train_batch(
        seq_len=configs['data']['sequence_length'],
        batch_size=configs['training']['batch_size'],
        normalise=configs['data']['normalise']
    ),
    epochs=configs['training']['epochs'],
    batch_size=configs['training']['batch_size'],
    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    save_dir=configs['model']['save_dir']
)

x_test, y_test = data.get_test_data(
    seq_len=configs['data']['sequence_length'],
    normalise=configs['data']['normalise']
)
predictions = model.predict_point_by_point(x_test)
#predictions = model.predict_sequences_multiple(x_test, configs['data']['sequence_length'], configs['data']['sequence_length'])
#plot_results_multiple(predictions, y_test, configs['data']['sequence_length'])
plot_results(predictions, y_test)
```

'''

Comment: Is `model` a tensorflow model? Pytorch model? Scikit? Keras? You haven't shown what exactly things are by removing the imports. In this case, the model should come from the LSTM repository's `Model` class which does have `predict_point_by_point`. Could you update with the actual error message?

Comment: All the codes are in the github folder. It's a keras model.